# Can I reclaim VAT on U.S services such as Domain hosting?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, accounting, vat

I have a bunch of regular payments paying for hosting and other digital services coming from the U.S.   There is no TAX stated on the invoices I receive and I'd assumed unless stated,  then I cannot claim VAT on such expenses.   (My business is VAT registered)

I read this article on the matter where the comments suggest otherwise http://www.accountingweb.co.uk/anyanswers/question/vat-domains-and-web-hosting-us

Can anyone help clarify this matter?

Thanks.

Comment: The US does not have a Value Added Tax; we do have sales taxes but they usually don't apply to services. If no tax was charged, i'd be surprised if tax treaties required the UK to credit you for tax paid.

Comment: Agreeing with @keshlam - On the US side of this you should not be paying any tax at all.  I have invoices for similar services (provided by a US company to me also in the US), and I pay no tax. Your invoice is reflecting no tax for this same reason.  How that plays on the UK side, I don't know.

Comment: You cannot reclaim VAT if you didn't pay any VAT. BTW, since the site you linked to requires registration, I suggest you quote the relevant text, since none of us is probably registered there.

Comment: Oo sorry about not being able to see the post, it came up from google for me and I'm not registered either so not sure why it's not showing for you.

Comment: The Answer in the post I was referring to was -----  In the above instance assuming the American supplier is not registered for UK, the customer will trat the supply as if made in the UK and will account for Output VAt on the charge and assuming they are fully taxable recover an identical amount as Input Tax.